# Unable to add certificate during Azure AD app integration

Tags: azure-active-directory, certificate, x509, pem

I encounter the following error when attempting to add a certificate, it's filename cert.pem, for an Azure AD app that I am integrating:

Failed to add certificate. Error detail: Upload a certificate (public key) with one of the following file types: .cer, .pem, .crt

I am sure that even though the file type is correct (.pem) the structure and content of the file is incorrect, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the content of the file is incorrect. You could create a certificate for testing purposes using PowerShell with [`New-SelfSignedCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2019-ps). Try to refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/signing-in-service-principal?view=azureadps-2.0#create-a-self-signed-certificate). Make sure you open PowerShell as an admin account.

```
$pwd = "<password>"
$currentDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $currentDate.AddYears(10) #10 years is nice and long
$thumb = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "techmikael.com" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -NotAfter $endDate).Thumbprint
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "cert:\localmachine\my\$thumb" -FilePath .\techmikael.pfx -Password $pwd
$path = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("$path\techmikael.pfx", $pwd)
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work